# Does minimum java.lang.Thread suspend time depend on OS or CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm investigating sub-millisecond pauses with `LockSupport.parkNanos(long)` and I ran this benchmark on two machines (MacOS with Intel Core i7 and Linux with Intel Core i5):

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class ParkNanosBenchmark {

  @Param({"10", "100", "1000", "10000", "1000000"})
  long delay;

  @Benchmark
  public void parkNanos() {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(delay);
  }
}
```

It yields the following results:

```
Linux

Benchmark                         (delay)  Mode  Cnt        Score      Error  Units
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos           10  avgt   40    57713.345 ±  165.827  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos          100  avgt   40    57672.554 ±  444.892  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos         1000  avgt   40    58646.654 ±  120.040  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos        10000  avgt   40    68222.650 ±  115.751  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos      1000000  avgt   40  1103499.893 ± 7793.704  ns/op

MacOS

Benchmark                         (delay)  Mode  Cnt        Score       Error  Units
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos           10  avgt   40    11395,046 ±   250,512  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos          100  avgt   40     9171,332 ±  1117,377  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos         1000  avgt   40     4781,591 ±    82,799  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos        10000  avgt   40    17750,419 ±   256,214  ns/op
ParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos      1000000  avgt   40  1403117,216 ± 42218,338  ns/op
```

Results are pretty much the same for Java 11 and 17, so regarding the results I've got two questions:

1. Are the results between Linux and MacOS depend on OS scheduler's granularity or is it more about the CPU?
2. Why are the MacOS results for delay 10...1000 are so widely spread?

Comment: The Java minimum resolution of 50us can be explained by the default value of 50us timer slack.  For more info see https://hazelcast.com/blog/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/.  I have no clue about OSX.